# Testing multiple columns for zero values at once?

Tags: vba, excel

(I am not a programmer and have no idea what I’m doing. This is my first VBA project)

So, I’m trying to hide columns with a zero value. So far, thanks to excelribbon.tips.net, I’ve managed to get this to work with the following (abbreviated) code

```
 Sub HideColumn1() 

   If Range(“H5”).Value = 0 Then 

     Columns(“H”).EntireColumn.Hidden = True  

   Else 

     Columns(“H”).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 

   End If

   ‘Repeat for everything between H and AG

   If Range(“AG5”).Value = 0 Then 

     Columns(“AG”).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 

   Else 

     Columns(“AG”).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 

   End If 

 End Sub
```

There has to be a way to do this that doesn’t include 180 lines of repetitive code? Plus when it runs it takes like ten seconds to bump through all the columns individually, and the charts go through some seizure-inducing flashing, and I’d just really rather it did it all at once. I tried changing it to

```
If Range(“H5:AG5”).Value = 0 Then 

  Columns(“H:AG”).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 

Else 

  Columns(“H:AG”).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 

End If
```

but that didn’t work. I also tried changing it to Range(“H5”,.....”AG5”) and Columns(“H5”,....”AG5”) for the sake of being thorough, even though I really didn’t expect it to work.

Can anyone help me please?

**Thanks so much everyone!!!**

Comment: Consider using [cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel) (IE: `If Cells(5, x).Value = 0`), along with loops (IE: `For x = 8 To [whatever AG is]`)

Comment: Do you distinguish between a cell containing 0 and a blank cell?

Comment: @sylphie you thank the people by marking the code you used as the correct code.  You mark it as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer that you used.  Even though more than one may work you only can mark one.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great first attempt Sylphie! You can use a loop to go through each column and check row 5 of that column. Also, to get rid of the flashing you can turn off `ScreenUpdating`, then turn it back on after the code is finished:

```
Sub HideColumn1()

Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 8 To 33 'H through AG
    If Cells(5, i).Value = 0 Then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This unhides all the columns, Loops and hides all the correct columns at once.  Should be quick and clean.

```
Sub HideColumn1()
ActiveSheet.Columns("H:AG").Hidden = False
For j = 8 To 33
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(5, j).Value = 0 Then
        Dim rng As Range
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, j)
        Else
            Set rng = Union(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, j), rng)
        End If
    End If
Next j

rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```